# How can I reference a resource (png) from a seperate project in the same solution

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My solution is structured as follows:

1. Class Library (Name = Chess)

   - Images

     - Pawn.png
2. WPF Core 3.1 Project (Name = ChessApp)

   - MainWindow.xaml

I want to show the Pawn.png image inside my **MainWindow.xaml** inide of an image tag.
When I have image files inside my WPF project, I can easily reference them by relative path.
When the resources are in a different project, I am not able to fix this.

My images inside the Image folder a have the build action **Resource** and are always copied to the output directory. The project **Chess** is correctly referenced inside **ChessApp**.

Obviously there are a lot of similar questions, but none of the answers worked for me.
All I have tried:

URI: [How to use Resources of from another project in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31715859/how-to-use-resources-of-from-another-project-in-wpf)

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Chess;Component/Images/Pawn.png"></Image>
```

Without URI: [How do I use an image from another project in my XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847897/how-do-i-use-an-image-from-another-project-in-my-xaml)

```
<Image Source="/Chess;Component/Images/Pawn.png"></Image>
```

So I don't know what to do.

**Workaround:** 
Add a property to a class which returns the full path of the image out of the relative one Path.GetFullPath(`@"..\..\..\..\Chess\Images\Pawn.png");`

Comment: From VS menu : Add Existing item.  Then Browser to file in other project.  The In Solution Explorer find file in Reference and Right Click.  Then select the copy option.  You could open the csproj file with Note Pad and make simple edits.

Comment: Those instructions are very unclear. The library should be used as a library (dll), the user shouldn't have to do additional steps.

Comment: As a note, if the Build Action is Resource, the files don't need to be copied to the Output Directory. They are compiled into the assembly.

Comment: And a correct fully qualified resource file pack URI would be `pack://application:,,,/Chess;component/Images/Pawn.png` with lowercase `;component` part.

Comment: In my question you can see I've already tried that and the ```component``` in lower case still hasn't solved the problem.

Comment: Is the name of the assembly  really `Chess`? Did you reference it from your application?

Comment: The project property window of project **Chess** says: ```Assembly Name = Chess```. Under references of ChessApp the project **Chess** is selected (referenced).

Answer (score 1):

Tried this with a plain `netcoreapp3.1` class library.

While in XAML Designer the ChessApp's MainWindow correctly shows the image resource, I see a `System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException` at runtime.

Changing the class library project's `Sdk` property from

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

to

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
```

fixed the problem.