# Images shows in design mode but not at runtime in WPF .net Core Project

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image, .net-core

I am using pack uri to get the image. It works well in design mode. The image shows without a problem but nothing appears at runtime. I am working in WPF .net Core application. Basically, I have two projects and I am trying to add the image from another project(same solution). I have added the reference for the project and set the image build action to resource already but still nothing happens.

`<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Test;component/Images/1.png" width="auto" height="auto"/>`

This is the mainWindow.xaml code. Test is the name of another project.
The exact same code works without problem in .Net Framework WPF application.

Comment: have you checked that the DLL of the project containing the images gets copied to your output folder?

Comment: what happens when using relative pack URI? "/Test;component/Images/1.png"? What happens when you set the image in code? img.UriSource = new Uri(...)

Comment: @SvenBardos Yes the Test.dll is copied to output directory i also tried relative pack uri but has the same effect and and seting image.Source in code with Uri and BitmapImage class throws the System.IO exception it can't locate the resource

Comment: the exact same code works without problem in .net framework WPF app.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60438642/1136211. Also be aware that no images files need to be copied to an output directory. Build Action Resource means that the image files is compiled into the assembly.

Comment: @Clemens oh thank you that helped. Turns out the Test project sdk was missing WindowsDesktop in the end. I've searched all over stackoverflow and never found that solution.

Comment: If someone upvotes the answer to the original question (or its owner eventually accepts it), we could close this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone has this problem [How can I reference a resource (png) from a seperate project in the same solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60433334/how-can-i-reference-a-resource-png-from-a-seperate-project-in-the-same-solutio/60438642#60438642) check this post. Basically your project sdk in .csproj file should look like this:
`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop>`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issue couple months ago during upgrading WPF applicating from .NET Frw to .NET Core.

Make sure that your resource in VS explorer is set to be in Build Action = "Resource"

[image]

and use this syntax as in the example below to referencing it for your XAML *Image* control:

```
pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/gray.png
```