# Reference .png from other project

Tags: wpf, resources

I'm trying to reference a .png from another project (both projects in same solution).

What I did:

- Added .png files to Resources folder of shared project.
- Set Build Action to Resource and Copy to Copy Always
- Referenced the shared project (with the .png) as ProjectReference (no package.config file anymore!)

  {cdeb6cf8-93fd-422d-959b-8fd1f30e00d8}
    Shared
- tryed to reference the .png with pack notation:

  ```
    <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/Shared;component/Resources/UnknownType.png"/>
  ```

But this does not work for me somehow...

What am I missing?

Comment: Is that a Style Setter, which should be `<Setter Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/Shared;component/Resources/UnknownType.png"/>`?

Comment: And is `Shared` the generated assembly name from `Shared.csproj`?

Comment: @Clemens thanks, was a typo here

Comment: @Clemens Yes Shared is the assmebly name

Comment: Maybe it's this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60438642/1136211

Comment: @Clemens It's set to Sdk, I Somehow cannot switch to Sdk.WindowsDesktop. Probably because it's a Net Standard 2.0 Librabry?

Comment: Maybe, try a  .NET Core Class Library. As another note, setting Copy Always is not necessary. Assembly resource files are compiled into the target assembly and do hence not need to be copied to the Output Directory.